# Get polygon from Azure Maps Search

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I'm trying to use Azure.Maps.Search to give me a polygon for a result. For example, if I search for "Birmingham" I would like a result for that municipality with a collection of geopoints defining the boundary.

Is this possible?

```cs
            var credential = new AzureKeyCredential("............");
            var client = new MapsSearchClient(credential);
            Response<SearchAddressResult> searchResult = await client.SearchAddressAsync(
                query: "Birmingham",
                options: new SearchAddressOptions
                {
                    ExtendedPostalCodesFor=new SearchIndex[] { SearchIndex.PointAddresses },
                    CountryFilter = new string[] { "GB" },
                    Top = 1,
                    EntityType = GeographicEntity.Municipality
                });
```

[image: Azure.Maps.Search result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The search address API will contain a `DataSources.Geometries.ID` value in the results that is the ID of the unique boundary for that result. You can take this ID and pass it into the `GetPolygonsAsync` API in the `Azure.Maps.Search` [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Maps.Search/).

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.Maps.Search;
using Azure.Maps.Search.Models;

namespace AzureMapsTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string MapsApiKey = "...........";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var credential = new AzureKeyCredential(MapsApiKey);
            var client = new MapsSearchClient(credential);
            SearchAddressOptions singleSearchResultOptions = new SearchAddressOptions { Top = 1 };
            Response<SearchAddressResult> searchResult =
                await client.SearchAddressAsync(
                    "Ealing, London, England",
                    singleSearchResultOptions);

            Response<PolygonResult> polygons =
                await client.GetPolygonsAsync(new string[] { searchResult.Value.Results[0].DataSources.Geometry.Id });

            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(polygons.Value.Polygons));
        }
    }
}
```